# NoMachine remote desktop flickering on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: remote-desktop, 23.10, desktop-sharing

Good morning everyone!

I am trying to share my desktop with Ubuntu 23.10 installed.

This machine has two GeForce RTX 2080 and consequently NVIDIA proprietary drivers (I need CUDA API so I cannot use open drivers), I am also using Gnome 45.1 together with Wayland.

I have tried to use NoMachine but, client side (another pc with Ubuntu 23.10 and the same configuration), the player shows me a black screen or a screen with a lot of flickering. On the host instead nothing happens, it just keeps going without any problems....

I also tried disabling hardware encoding, OpenGL acceleration and using H.264 as a codec, both on the host and client side, but nothing changed. Another test I did was to use the same refresh rate of the monitors (60 Hz) and disable fractional scaling on both machines but nothing.

How can I solve this ? Thanks